# How do I convert dates from Open Office format to MS Excel format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc, date-time

I am trying to save a file in Libre Office as an excel file but Excel sees the data  displays it as a negative number using a series of ###### symbols.

I believe the problem is to do with the two systems using different base dates to calculate. Can anyone suggest a formula that works

Comment: Are those symbols appear exactly also in the formula bar in Excel?

Comment: Since Excel has severe limitations regarding date-handling (no pre-1900 dates possible), a complete solution depends on the range of dates involved in your use case. Preliminarily, i've created an answer concerning the problem of displaying negative dates as ######.

Answer (score 2):

Converting dates from OOo/LO Calc to MS Excel has to consider Excel's inherent restrictions regarding  the handling of dates (see [HP005199291](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx) regarding Excel 2003 and [HP010342495](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) for Excel 2013). Especially, Excel doesn't support calculations for dates before 1900. You can enter such dates in Excel only as strings, using the apostrophe to mark the cell content explicitly as string. So, i fear there's no overall solution for converting dates between the two office suits that cover every possible use case.

To be sure, there's a quick solution making Excel to display dates instead of `#################` symbols: [change the epoch to the **1904 date system**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162/en-us). But **this won't solve your initial problem** (see below). To change the date system, open "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" and look for the "`Calculation`" section. In my german-localized version, the options dialogue looks like this:

[image]

Calc is able to use the 1904 date system, too. Open Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`Libreoffice Calc`" -> "`Calculate`":

[image]

**But**... if you create the following sheet with Libreoffice Calc (with 1904 system enabled) ...

[image]

*(Column B showing the formulas from Column A; the date in `A4` isn't a formula result but manually entered)*

... Excel will display the same sheet as follows (Excel will enable the 1904 system automatically, if Calc was set to use that system):

[image]

So, Excel calculates the negative date value in `A3` differenty from Calc, even in 1904 mode. Same is true for dates before 1904-01-02 (see `A4`). So, you will have to adjust the date values in Excel in any case.

Comment: tohuwawohu's answer was helpful in revealing the limitations of Excel but the conversion doesn't work for pre 1900 dates. Excel doesn't get it!    This  made me think of how to extract the data from the Libre Office date and eventually found that using the DAY MONTH and YEAR functions  to  3 separate cells further along the row and then copying and using Paste Special - Number which gives a numeric value recorded under Day Month or Year This is then recognised by Excel as numeric values which can be sorted This  could be useful to anyone doing family history  sa you use pre 1900 dates